# Is it possible to integrate the mapping capabilities of QGIS with Stata?

Tags: qgis, stata

I was wondering  of the possibility of integrating the mapping capabilities of Q-GIS with Stata, by using the programming aspect of Stata as opposed to using R or python.

Is this possible?

Comment: QGIS is python based so is there a Stata python library? MIT do http://presbrey.mit.edu/PyDTA

Comment: *Anything* is possible with enough work. But integrating QGIS with Stata would take far more work than it would ever be worth. Stata uses two antique proprietary scripting languages which are essentially just a macro expansion wrapper around its internal statistical computational procedures. Think instead about creating a file-sharing mechanism to move back and forth between Stata and QGIS.